# DocFX (VB.net) - VB code comment not rendering properly

Tags: vb.net, comments, docfx

DocFX is not rendering VB code comment properly. It looks like its considering the comment quote as the beginning of a string.

My code looks like:

```
''' <summary>
''' This class will help external applications to communicate with API and vice versa.
''' </summary>
''' <example>
''' Connect to Base
''' Create an Object of BaseController. Set license parameters. Call the "Connect" method with parameters (Multiple port addresses can also be sent) or call "ConnectAllBases".
''' <code>
''' 'Set the license files directory path.
''' baseControllerObject.LicenseFolderPath = "C:\Common" 
''' 'Set application ID of the base.
''' baseControllerObject.SetAppID(6) 
''' 'This Event will be raised On calling "ConnectAllBases" when auto-detection Of bases will be completed.
''' AddHandler() baseControllerObject.HardwareInitializationComplete, AddressOf Base_HardwareInitializationComplete 
''' 'For USB and Ethernet Base   
''' BaseControllerObject.ConnectMyVote(baseID:=2)
''' 'For MyVote Base BaseControllerObject.ConnectEnjoy(typeName:="rf219”, port:"hid://12345678”, minID:1, maxID:400) 'For Enjoy Base
''' BaseControllerObject.Connect(portAddress:="COM7") 
''' 'To auto-detect Enjoy bases. 
''' BaseControllerObject.ConnectAllEnjoyBases() 
''' 'To auto-detect SunVote bases. 
''' BaseControllerObject.ConnectAllMyVoteBases() 
''' 'To auto-detect ProVote bases. 
''' BaseControllerObject.ConnectAllProVoteBases()
''' </code>
''' </example>
```

[Actual Behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtIBV.png)